# MapReduce job with identity Mapper fails with "Type mismatch in key from map"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Just for learning basis, I am trying to create a MapReduce program without defining the mapper and reducer in driver class, so in case it uses identity mapper and reducer. It is working fine if i only comment reducer but giving error when i comment both. Below is my driver class code. Please suggest.

Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "word count");
job.setJarByClass(WordCountRun.class);

// job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
//job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);  

//job.setNumReduceTasks(0);


job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);  

// job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH12T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample does not call [`Job#setInputFormatClass`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setInputFormatClass(java.lang.Class)).  If the input format is not set explicitly, then the default [`InputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) is [`TextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html).

With `TextInputFormat`, the keys input to the mapper are [`LongWritable`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/LongWritable.html) instances representing the offset within the input file.  The values input to the mapper are [`Text`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html).

Since you are using the identity mapper and there is no reducer specified, the job's output is specified by the mapper.  The identity mapper outputs whatever was input, so it receives (`LongWritable` -> `Text`) tuples as input and outputs the same (`LongWritable` -> `Text`) tuples as output.

The problem in your code sample is this line:

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
```

This attempts to specify that the job's output keys are `Text`, but as discussed above, the output keys for this job are actually `LongWritable`.  This causes the error in your image:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

If you remove the call to `Job#setOutputKeyClass`, then the error will no longer occur.

Another way to think about this is to consider that the default MapReduce job effectively does this:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setPartitionerClass(HashPartitioner.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

By calling `job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class)`, the job submission violated assumptions of the other settings in the default MapReduce job.